# I'm unable to open robo3t 1.1.1 in cent os7

Tags: linux, centos7, robo3t

I'm a beginner in linux environment . But after a lot of reference I was able to download the `robo3t` from it's official website and unzipped that. But now from the bin folder I'm unable to open the `robo3t` even I'm not getting any error . I also tried to follow questions both in `SO` and in other places but I couldn't solve my problem.

List of things I tried:

- Tried to place libstdc++.so.6* files in folder robo-backup
- Tried to delete above files from lib folder(as per some advises)
- Tried to re-extract the archive

When I tried to open `robo3t` by terminal two errors popped up

- `./robo3t: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /home/srinu/Downloads/robomongo/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6)` //in this case the `libstd` files are in lib folder
- `./robo3t: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./robo3t)
  ./robo3t: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./robo3t)` //this error came up after deleting the files from libs folder

Comment: CentOS 7 has `glibc-2.17` and `libstdc++-4.8.2` . 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20' is an object in `libstdc++-4.9.x` .

Comment: More info on [centos.org/forums](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=64556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the official website of `robo3t` and it was saying that it's currently unavailable for centOS 7

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

$ sudo yum install epel-release

$ sudo yum install snapd

$ sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket

$ sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap

$ sudo snap install robo3t-snap

I have Cent0s 8 - I'm not sure how it works in version 7.

Regards!